# Port Forwarding using iptables on Open-Mesh

Tags: iptables, openwrt, port-forwarding

A quick overview for those who are unfamiliar with Open-Mesh:

The system uses small wireless access points that automagically build their own mesh network. As long as one of the access points is connected to the internet through a wired LAN (making that access point the "gateway"), all the access points (and their wireless clients) will have internet access.

The access points run a modified version of OpenWRT.

Normally, the only way to SSH into any of the wireless access points (nodes) is to first SSH into the gateway, *then* SSH from there to the node.

**What I'm trying to do:** Open/forward a port to SSH into each wireless node directly.

For example, my gateway is at `10.45.13.220` on my LAN. The first wireless node is at `5.12.252.248` on the mesh network (i.e. typing `ssh root@5.12.252.248` while logged into the gateway will open a shell to the wireless node). I would like to be able to log into the wireless node like so:

```
$ ssh -p 11001 root@10.45.13.220
```

So I tried forwarding that port in `iptables` using the following commands:

```
$ iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 10.45.13.220 --dport 11001 \
          -j DNAT --to-destination 5.12.252.248:22

$ iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 5.12.252.248 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT`
```

I know this is doing *something* because when I try to SSH to `10.45.13.220:11001` (from another computer on the network) before entering the above commands, the connection is refused. But once the commands have been entered, **the connection times out.**

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I'm pretty new to `iptables`, but this seems like it should be pretty straightforward.

**Note:** IP forwarding is already enabled

**EDIT: Logging Results**

After setting up logging for both rules suggested by @slm, this is what `dmesg` spits out when I try to connect to 10.45.13.220:11001 from another linux box:

```
[1015021.850000] IN=br-lan1 OUT= MAC=ac:86:74:0c:fd:00:6c:62:6d:12:85:9d:08:00 \
SRC=10.45.13.246 DST=10.45.13.220 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=16916 DF \
PROTO=TCP SPT=41908 DPT=11001 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0

[1015021.850000] IN=br-lan1 OUT=br-lan1 MAC=ac:86:74:0c:fd:00:6c:62:6d:12:85:9d:08:00 \
SRC=10.45.13.246 DST=5.12.252.248 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=16916 DF \
PROTO=TCP SPT=41908 DPT=22 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0

[1015022.850000] IN=br-lan1 OUT=br-lan1 MAC=ac:86:74:0c:fd:00:6c:62:6d:12:85:9d:08:00 \
RC=10.45.13.246 DST=5.12.252.248 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=16917 DF \
PROTO=TCP SPT=41908 DPT=22 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

New iptables rules used (as per @slm's suggestion):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 11001 -j LOG --log-level debug
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 11001 -j DNAT --to 5.12.252.248:22
iptables -A FORWARD -i br-lan1 -p tcp -j LOG --log-level debug
iptables -A FORWARD -i br-lan1 -o bat0.2@bat0 -p tcp -d 5.12.252.248 --dport 22 \
    -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't necessary with `ssh`. You can ssh through one host to another host like so:

```
$ ssh -t serverA ssh serverB
```

#### Example

```
$ hostname
grinchy

$ ssh -t skinner ssh mulder
Last login: Fri Aug 16 18:19:56 2013 from skinner.somedom.net

$ hostname
mulder.somedom.net
$
```

#### iptables

If you absolutely want to forward the port I believe this rule will do it:

```
$ iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 10.45.13.220 --dport 11001 -j DNAT --to 5.12.252.248:22
$ iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -p tcp -d 5.12.252.248 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Where eth1 is exterior interface and eth0 is the interior interface.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help! I won't be able to try this out until I'm back at the office on Monday, but I'll let you know how it goes (and mark as answered if all goes well).

Comment: @KyleG. - give it a try, it might need to be adjusted, let me know and I can help out.

Comment: Just gave it a try but I'm still having the same issue. Do you know if there are any logs I can check to shed some light on where the communication is failing? I'm also looking at a way to implement your first suggestion, but it doesn't look like the C# SSH library I'm using supports hopping like that.

Comment: Ok I've got it logging. Please see the edit to my question above.

Comment: @KyleG. - did you adapt the rules I provided? If so could you add those to your Edit you made just so I can see what you ultimately ended up using?

Comment: I did, will add them above

Comment: @KyleG. - the `-o bat0.2@bat0` seems like an issue to me. Notice that no messages are targeting that interface so that rule never gets applied. Try removing the `-o ...` bit from that command and see it works then.

Comment: I noticed the same thing and already tried that. There's probably a lot going on with this system that isn't immediately apparent. Given the simplicity of what I need to do (run a script on each node) I've decided to build a "middleman" daemon to run on the gateway. Thanks for your help!